# how to read check box elements using Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I Wanted to check whether specific answers are checked in Jquery

```
<label><input type="checkbox" class="q1" name="q1" id="q1-a" />aaa</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="q1" name="q1" id="q1-b" />bbb</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="q1" name="q1" id="q1-c" />ccc</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="q1" name="q1" id="q1-d" />ddd</label>
```

I have jquery code to check nummber of boxed checked but hot to know whether 1 and 2 options are checked

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked:visible').length == 2
```

Comment: This is a **very** basic question. Sufficient information is provided in the always-useful [jQuery API documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/) I suggest you start there.

Comment: im very new to jquery and i need it very urgently can u please suggest something other than that tutorial....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this

```
// At first get all the checked items
var checked = $('.q1:checked').get();

// then loop through the array and check their ids
if(checked) {
    $.each(checked, function(){
        console.log(this.id); // q1-a, q1-b, q1-c, q1-d (if checked)
    });
}
```

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BELH3/). There maybe other easy ways but not sure what you are trying to do.

**Update :** you may try this

```
$('.btnNext1').on('click', function(){
    if( $('#q1-a').is(':checked') || $('#q1-b').is(':checked') ) {
        return false;
    }

    // do whatever you want to do when one of those are not checked
});
```

[Check this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BELH3/1/)

Comment: i just wanted to check whether q1-a and q1-b are checked are not if they are not checked i should return false.

Comment: you can check `if(this.id == 'q1-a' || this.id == 'q1-ba')` then `return false` in the loop (it means, if any one of q1-a and b).

Comment: can i use like this `$('.btnNext1').click(function(){
    var checked = $('.q1:checked').get();
    if(!(this.id == 'q1-a' || this.id == 'q1-ba'))
    {
    return false;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#q1-a').is(':checked');
$('#q1-b').is(':checked');
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the length and you'll get an array of the selected elements:

```
var checked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked:visible'); //array of checked checkboxes
```

Comment: i wanted to check whether options 1 and 2 are checked i mean q1-a and q1-b??